# Can a pod with default ServiceAccount deploy pods in another cluster?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes question.

We have a master pod that can deploy other pods depending on the REST endpoint called. For example, if someone calls "/start_work" endpoint, it can deploy a worker pod to do the work related with this request.

This master pod is deployed with default ServiceAccount, and to allow it to deploy other pods, we had to give it cluster-admin access. We used ClusterRoleBinding to tie the default ServiceAccount to a cluster-admin role.

However, we have a more challenging problem now where our master pod is running in one cluster, but the worker pod needs to be deployed in another cluster. Does this sound achievable ? Giving the default ServiceAccount cluster-admin access can't help us if we're talking about another cluster, right?

Has anyone done this before? How did you achieve this ?

Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

> However, we have a more challenging problem now where our master pod is running in one cluster, but the worker pod needs to be deployed in another cluster. Does this sound achievable ?

Certainly, yes; you are free to provide credentials via any number of supported mechanisms that would give the Pod a well-formed KUBECONFIG that can talk to the remote cluster at whatever access level of your comfort. By *default* the injected `ServiceAccount` is trusted by only its own cluster, but there are seemingly infinite ways of providing the component parts or a fully formed KUBECONFIG into a Pod's filesystem, and then you're off to the races

> Giving the default ServiceAccount cluster-admin access can't help us if we're talking about another cluster, right?

That depends *(is always the answer!)* on whether the two clusters share a common CA root; if the answer is yes, then yes, `cluster-admin` on one will become `cluster-admin` on both. The `Subject` is determined by the `CN=` (and sometimes `OU=`/`O=`) of the presented x509 certificate, and its validity is determined by the chain-of-trust between the presented certificate and the api-server of the cluster